# C Multiple Conditions While Loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Not sure if I'm just very tired/delirious and failing to see what I've done wrong here.

```
i = 7
decTemp = -62
while((i >= 0) && (abs(decTemp >= 1))){
    /* do stuff */
    i--;
}
```

This while loop gets skipped completely, I've checked and it seems that the condition is not met at all which is bizarre since i is greater than 0 and the absolute value of decTemp is greater than 1. Please help :((

Comment: what do you think `abs(decTemp >= 1)` will do? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Have you run in a debugger or printed the pieces so you can confirm everything is what you think it is?

Comment: You should learn to look at the places you're putting ().

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to say `abs(decTemp) >= 1`, and not `abs(decTemp >= 1)`.

Since `-62 >= 1` is false (`0`), `abs(0)` is also `0`. So the `while` loop condition is always false.

Pro tip: *always* put constants on the left.

```
while ((0 <= i) && (1 <= abs(decTemp))) {
    i--;
}
```

Comment: I'm definitely too tired haha, went a bit code-blind. Thanks!